# Easiest way to map Azure Table Storage Data Model in Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-table-storage

When I want to add my javascript objects (or entities) to my Azure Table Storage, I first need to run them through the `entityGenerator`.

My objects could look like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'foo',
  timestamp: new Date()
}
```

The entities I need to pass to the `TableService` are going to look like this:

```
{
  id: { '_': 1, '$': 'Edm.Int32' },
  name: { '_': 'foo', '$': 'Edm.String' },
  timestamp:{ '_': new Date(), '$': 'Edm.DateTime' },
}
```

This is also the format in which the entities are returned from the `TableService`.

To map my objects to the correct format for sending them to my Table Storage is pretty straightforward, but I haven't found an easy way to convert the returned entities form my service back to regular JavaScript objects I can easily work with.

I could create some sort of generic mapper function to get the values out of the `_` property on the entities, but it seems that some metadata properties are also passed into the entities itself.

**Does anyone know of an easy way to map between JavaScript objects and Azure Table Storage entities?**

Is (or should) this functionality be included in the `azure-storage` library?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but decided that I simply did not need the metadata for my particular DAO and application (nodejs).

Ended up using map on the result.entries and returned an object that is cleaned up.

```
  Object.keys(row).forEach((key) => {
     newRow[key] = row[key]['_']; 
  });
```

I agree that azurestorage should include a more straightforward manner for inserting and removing data. I have to build out a map/reduce wrapper of sorts for the query builder so that it does not flood the rest of the application with extra stuff. IOW I want a simple DAO class for NodeJS. Perhaps we can build one together?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles upon this: you can access the values in the `body` part of `response`. The result contains the actual table entity.

So to access the name part in the example use `response.body.name`.

Answer (score -1):

As The Azure Storage SDK for Node is implemented with Storage Rest APIs. To use Azure Storage resources, you can leverage SDK and implement with Rest APIs yourself.

And according the API reference, E.G. [Insert Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179433.aspx), we need to generate the request body like :

```
{
   "Address":"Mountain View",
   "Age":23,
   "AmountDue":200.23,
   "CustomerCode@odata.type":"Edm.Guid",
   "CustomerCode":"c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a79-3e9149a57833",
   "CustomerSince@odata.type":"Edm.DateTime",
   "CustomerSince":"2008-07-10T00:00:00",
   "IsActive":true,
   "NumberOfOrders@odata.type":"Edm.Int64",
   "NumberOfOrders":"255",
   "PartitionKey":"mypartitionkey",
   "RowKey":"myrowkey"
}
```

Which means we need to defind the type of the properties in the body.

So the easiest way to generate the table entities in my opinion is to use the Azure Storage SDK via [`entityGenerator`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/tableutilities.js#L106) function.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I understand the need of the entityGenerator, but I am wondering if it's possible to return the raw values from the TableService (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/internal/odatahandler.js#L155). I don't need all of these OData types and metadata on my JavaScript objects once they are fetched from my table. Is there any way to return this rawEntity from the odatahandler?